# iOS Universal Link With PRIVATE domain

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, universal

I am trying setup iOS universal link with a private server. I put my apple-app-site-association on my private_domain/apple-app-site-association . 
However, iOS can not download the Apple-app-site-association from server even testing device in the same network as my private domain . I am wondering if it possible to set up Universal Link with Private Domain  ? Thanks

Comment: Is your private domain reachable via https? The file must be reachable with https to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, no. You'll see in the device logs, if you watch during app installation, that setup of universal links is failing because the domain cannot be reached.

You can work around this by creating a public domain (just use an Azure site or something similar). The apple-app-site-association must exist as a static file. Note that if you are using Azure you'll need to add a file handler for the empty file extension and another file handler for Android's json file extension if you're doing Android as well.

If you want the links to work for web as well then just have the paths redirect to your internal (private) domain.